# Pearmeability of various materials by EM-waves of cell-phones

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

Is there any way I can show (even if approximately) that one needs x cm of glass, y cm of brick, z cm of reinforced concrete, etc. to block cell-phone signal of a certain frequency and strength? I need it for the infographics at a mobile provider web site.